# Parsing XML file using element tree python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree

I want to parse an XML file fragment given below to extract the viewpoint tag and its attribute names. I also want to create a table to tabulate the extracted data.

My XML file fragment:

```xml
 <windows source-height='51'>
        <window class='dashboard' maximized='true' name='Figure 8-59'>
          <viewpoints>
            <viewpoint name='Good Filter Design'>
              <zoom type='entire-view' />
              <geo-search-visibility value='1' />
            </viewpoint>
            <viewpoint name='Poor Filter Design'>
              <zoom type='entire-view' />
              <geo-search-visibility value='1' />
            </viewpoint>
          </viewpoints>
          <active id='-1' />
        </window>
        <window class='dashboard' name='Figure 8-60 thought 8-65'>
          <viewpoints>
            <viewpoint name='Heat Map'>
              <zoom type='entire-view' />
              <geo-search-visibility value='1' />
            </viewpoint>
            <viewpoint name='Lightbulb'>
              <zoom type='entire-view' />
              <geo-search-visibility value='1' />
            </viewpoint>
            <viewpoint name='Sales Histogram'>
              <zoom type='entire-view' />
              <geo-search-visibility value='1' />
            </viewpoint>
          </viewpoints>
          <active id='-1' />
        </window>
</windows>
```

I want to extract and keep the `"good filter design"` and `"poor filter design"` in one row and the remaining three view point names as a second row.

My attempt:

```py
root = getroot('example.xml')
for i in root.findall('windows/window/viewpoints/viewpoint'):
    print(i.get('name'))
```

Comment: Use Beautifulsoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using elementtree should be as easy. I don't know what `getroot()` do exactly, but if it really return root element of the XML document, then you shouldn't mention `window` in the `findall` parameter :

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> raw = '''your XML string'''
>>> root = ET.fromstring(raw)
>>> for v in root.findall('window/viewpoints'):
...     print([a.get('name') for a in v.findall('viewpoint')])
... 
['Good Filter Design', 'Poor Filter Design']
['Heat Map', 'Lightbulb', 'Sales Histogram']
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](https://eval.in/957975)</kbd>**

Comment: how can i add 1st two values in a list and next three values 'heatmap , lightbulb, sales histogram' in another list ?

Comment: tq @har07 for your quick response

Comment: List that u defined is static, so in my problem this list order as well as numbers may differ. Any idea how to generate list dynamically.? @har07

Answer (score 0):

If you can use beautifulsoup thismuch easy it is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#xml = """your xml"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'lxml')
names = [viewpt["name"] for viewpt in soup.find_all('viewpoint')]
```

This will give every tag named 'viewpoint'

If you only want nested one use this:

```
names = [viewpoint["name"]
        for windows in soup.find_all('windows')
            for window in windows.find_all("window")
                for viewpoints in window.find_all("viewpoints")
                    for viewpoint in viewpoints.find_all("viewpoint")]
```

in your case both will give:

```
Out[18]: 
['Good Filter Design',
 'Poor Filter Design',
 'Heat Map',
 'Lightbulb',
 'Sales Histogram']
```